# Sum of numbers of a column of CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, algorithmic-trading

>The column has first OPEN in first error and then all the numbers(around 50 numbers for 50 different days)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable -->
**strong text**

```
import csv
with open("TCS_PAST.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    next(readCSV)

    for row in readCSV:
        a = float(row[3].replace(",",""))
        print (a)
        print(sum(a)) -->
```

Comment: Would it be good to share the content of csv?

Comment: It has several rows as well as column .. First line(Top Most) has name and below that contain numbers .. say column-3 has OPEN in first row and on wards it's opening value for 50 days around like .. Values can be 2,486.50 2269, 568 and etc...(contains comma sometimes and decimal as well

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess what you are trying to accomplish here, but let me try:

- the commas are already removed by `csv.reader()`, no need in calling `replace()`
- each line returned by `csv.reader()` is a list of strings which are floating numbers from your file. If you want to process elements starting with the third one you should write

  a = [float(x) for x in row[3:]]

then `a` would be an array of floating numbers.